# Application error on Azure App Service trying to run Java/Springboot jar

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

Trying to deploy/run a springbok application (jar) on Azure App Service, but seeing an "Application Error".

[image]

**Application**

We built the application using Springboot and wanted to deploy the prebuilt jar file (from /target" folder.

**Azure Setup**

1. Created a new App Service using Java 11
2. Under "Deployment Center" linked with the Github repository that holds the code and jar file under `/target`
   [image]
3. Under App service > Configuration > General Settings > Startup Command
   `java -jar /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

   [image]

**Logs**

```
2021-05-05T22:25:23.730536337Z STARTUP_FILE=
2021-05-05T22:25:23.737427449Z STARTUP_COMMAND=java -jar /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2021-05-05T22:25:23.738113651Z No STARTUP_FILE available.
2021-05-05T22:25:23.738719652Z Running STARTUP_COMMAND: java -jar /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2021-05-05T22:25:24.003600232Z Finished running startup command 'java -jar /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'. Exiting with exit code 1.
2021-05-05T22:25:24.004755134Z Error: Unable to access jarfile /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Are we missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that app service cant find your jar file.

> Unable to access jarfile /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I think when you deployed from target then you jar is possible in root. Go to App Service Editor inside of your app and check location for your jar

Comment: Not sure where to find App Service Editor? But I verified.. the jar file is in GitHub project `lead-processing/target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` which is my Startup Command `java -jar /target/lead-processing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` . And in Deployment Center the Github repo is set to the same project where the jar file is in.

Comment: @SurenKonathala https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "/" right before the target works for me